# Order of the center of a group - odd?

Tags: group-theory

I was just thinking, does the order of the center of a group have to be odd? If not, then there is definitely something wrong with my reasoning in the following proof.

Suppose the center of a group $G$ is of even order. The center contains the identity element, so there are an odd number of elements in $Z(G)$ if we disregard the identity element. However, if an element $g$ is in $Z(G)$, then so is $g^{-1}$. Moreover, each element has a unique inverse. This would imply that there is at least one element in $Z(G)$ whose inverse is not in $Z(G)$, which isn't possible - its inverse must be in $Z(G)$. Contradiction.

Although this seems trivial, I feel like I neglected something. Can you see anything that I've neglected? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Note that you don't use any property of $Z(G)$: every subgroup contains the identity and is closer under inverses.

Comment: The center of an abelian group is itself. Your argument would imply that there were no abelian groups of even order.

Comment: Also, $|G|  = 2^n$ is always a possibility, so any such group with non-trivial center will have a center of even order. Your idea is interesting, but you are overlooking elements of order $2$.

Comment: I now see all of the incorrect things that stem from my faulty logic. @Michael pinpointed this in his answer, and so did David Wheeler's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g^{-1}$ may equal $g$, so they wouldn't come in pairs.
For example, $Z_6$ is abelian, so its centre is the whole group.  The odd one out is 3, because $-3=3\pmod6$

Comment: I think this is definitely where my errors stemmed from. Thanks!